# Perl Error while writing SnmpGet Command function 

Tags: perl, net-snmp

While Executing 1 perl file .....M getting this problem

**Unrecognized character \x03; marked by <-- HERE after PK<-- HERE near column 3 at mibwalk.pl line 1.**

AnyBody have any idea about it

```
Code--->

#!usr/bin/perl
use BER;
use SNMP_util;
use SNMP_Session;
$MIB1 = “sysLocation.0”;
$HOST = “192.168.1.150”;
($value) = &snmpget(“public\@$HOST”,”$MIB1”);
if($value) {
            print “Results :$MIB1: :$value:\n”; 
}   
  else { warn “No response from host :$HOST:\n”; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the string in hex-format.
In my case this was not possible with the NET::SNMP module.

So I modifided the source code of this module to make it possible.
I used the following version of `Net::SNMP`:

```
SNMP.pm,v 5.3 2005/10/20 14:17:01
Version v5.2.0
```

See at bottom of this post for the details.

Now you can use the `set_request()` function of `Net::SNMP` with a new ASN.1 type HEX_STRING.

e.g.:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SNMP;

my $OID_sysContact = '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0';

my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
      -hostname  => shift || 'localhost',
      -community => shift || 'public',
   );

my $rv = $session->set_request(-varbindlist => [ $OID_sysContact, HEX_STRING, 'FF0a1200' ],);

$session->close();
exit 0;


# ============================================================================
package Net::SNMP;

# $Id: SNMP.pm,v 5.3 2005/10/20 14:17:01 dtown Rel $
# [...]
# ============================================================================

use strict;

## Validate the version of Perl

BEGIN 
{
   die('Perl version 5.6.0 or greater is required') if ($] < 5.006);
}

## Version of the Net::SNMP module

our $VERSION = v5.2.0;

## Load our modules

use Net::SNMP::Dispatcher();
use Net::SNMP::PDU qw( :ALL );
use Net::SNMP::Security();
use Net::SNMP::Transport qw( :ports );

## Handle importing/exporting of symbols

use Exporter();

our @ISA = qw( Exporter );

our @EXPORT = qw(
   INTEGER INTEGER32 OCTET_STRING OBJECT_IDENTIFIER IPADDRESS COUNTER
   COUNTER32 GAUGE GAUGE32 UNSIGNED32 TIMETICKS OPAQUE COUNTER64 NOSUCHOBJECT
   NOSUCHINSTANCE ENDOFMIBVIEW snmp_dispatcher HEX_STRING 
);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( snmp_event_loop oid_context_match );

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
   asn1        => [ 
      qw( INTEGER INTEGER32 OCTET_STRING NULL OBJECT_IDENTIFIER SEQUENCE
          IPADDRESS COUNTER COUNTER32 GAUGE GAUGE32 UNSIGNED32 TIMETICKS
          OPAQUE COUNTER64 NOSUCHOBJECT NOSUCHINSTANCE ENDOFMIBVIEW
          GET_REQUEST GET_NEXT_REQUEST GET_RESPONSE SET_REQUEST TRAP
          GET_BULK_REQUEST INFORM_REQUEST SNMPV2_TRAP REPORT HEX_STRING )
   ],
# [...]
# no more changes in source code of Net::SNMP
# [...] only changes in description of Net::SNMP
# [documentation] ------------------------------------------------------------

=head1 EXPORTS

The Net::SNMP module uses the F<Exporter> module to export useful constants 
and subroutines.  These exportable symbols are defined below and follow the
rules and conventions of the F<Exporter> module (see L<Exporter>).

=over

=item Default

&snmp_dispatcher, INTEGER, INTEGER32, OCTET_STRING, OBJECT_IDENTIFIER, 
IPADDRESS, COUNTER, COUNTER32, GAUGE, GAUGE32, UNSIGNED32, TIMETICKS, 
OPAQUE, COUNTER64, NOSUCHOBJECT, NOSUCHINSTANCE, ENDOFMIBVIEW HEX_STRING

=item Exportable

&snmp_debug, &snmp_dispatcher, &snmp_type_ntop, &oid_base_match, &oid_lex_sort, 
&ticks_to_time, INTEGER, INTEGER32, OCTET_STRING, NULL, OBJECT_IDENTIFIER, 
SEQUENCE, IPADDRESS, COUNTER, COUNTER32, GAUGE, GAUGE32, UNSIGNED32, TIMETICKS,
OPAQUE, COUNTER64, NOSUCHOBJECT, NOSUCHINSTANCE, ENDOFMIBVIEW, GET_REQUEST,
GET_NEXT_REQUEST, GET_RESPONSE, SET_REQUEST, TRAP, GET_BULK_REQUEST,
INFORM_REQUEST, SNMPV2_TRAP, REPORT, DEBUG_ALL, DEBUG_NONE, DEBUG_MESSAGE,
DEBUG_TRANSPORT, DEBUG_DISPATCHER,DEBUG_PROCESSING, DEBUG_SECURITY, COLD_START,
WARM_START, LINK_DOWN, LINK_UP,AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, EGP_NEIGHBOR_LOSS,
ENTERPRISE_SPECIFIC, SNMP_VERSION_1,SNMP_VERSION_2C, SNMP_VERSION_3, SNMP_PORT,
SNMP_TRAP_PORT, TRANSLATE_NONE,TRANSLATE_OCTET_STRING, TRANSLATE_NULL,
TRANSLATE_TIMETICKS, TRANSLATE_OPAQUE,TRANSLATE_NOSUCHOBJECT,
TRANSLATE_NOSUCHINSTANCE, TRANSLATE_ENDOFMIBVIEW, TRANSLATE_UNSIGNED, 
TRANSLATE_ALL HEX_STRING

=item Tags

=over 

=item :asn1

INTEGER, INTEGER32, OCTET_STRING, NULL, OBJECT_IDENTIFIER, SEQUENCE, 
IPADDRESS, COUNTER, COUNTER32, GAUGE, GAUGE32, UNSIGNED32, TIMETICKS, OPAQUE, 
COUNTER64, NOSUCHOBJECT, NOSUCHINSTANCE, ENDOFMIBVIEW, GET_REQUEST, 
GET_NEXT_REQUEST, GET_RESPONSE, SET_REQUEST, TRAP, GET_BULK_REQUEST, 
INFORM_REQUEST, SNMPV2_TRAP, REPORT, HEX_STRING

=item :debug

&snmp_debug, DEBUG_ALL, DEBUG_NONE, DEBUG_MESSAGE, DEBUG_TRANSPORT, 
DEBUG_DISPATCHER, DEBUG_PROCESSING, DEBUG_SECURITY

=item :generictrap

COLD_START, WARM_START, LINK_DOWN, LINK_UP, AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE,
EGP_NEIGHBOR_LOSS, ENTERPRISE_SPECIFIC

=item :snmp

&snmp_debug, &snmp_dispatcher, &snmp_type_ntop, &oid_base_match, &oid_lex_sort, 
&ticks_to_time, SNMP_VERSION_1, SNMP_VERSION_2C, SNMP_VERSION_3, SNMP_PORT,
SNMP_TRAP_PORT

=item :translate

TRANSLATE_NONE, TRANSLATE_OCTET_STRING, TRANSLATE_NULL, TRANSLATE_TIMETICKS,
TRANSLATE_OPAQUE, TRANSLATE_NOSUCHOBJECT, TRANSLATE_NOSUCHINSTANCE, 
TRANSLATE_ENDOFMIBVIEW, TRANSLATE_UNSIGNED, TRANSLATE_ALL

=item :ALL

All of the above exportable items.

=back

=back

=head1 EXAMPLES
# [...]

# ============================================================================
1; # [end Net::SNMP]
```

**Net::SNMP::Message**

```
# ============================================================================
package Net::SNMP::Message;

# $Id: Message.pm,v 2.3 2005/10/20 14:17:01 dtown Rel $

# Object used to represent a SNMP message. 

# Copyright (c) 2001-2005 David M. Town <dtown@cpan.org>
# All rights reserved.

# This program is free software; you may redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the same terms as Perl itself.

# ============================================================================

use strict;
use bytes;

use Math::BigInt();

## Version of the Net::SNMP::Message module

our $VERSION = v2.0.3;

## Handle importing/exporting of symbols

use Exporter();

our @ISA = qw( Exporter );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( TRUE FALSE );

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
   generictrap    => [
      qw( COLD_START WARM_START LINK_DOWN LINK_UP AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE
          EGP_NEIGHBOR_LOSS ENTERPRISE_SPECIFIC )
   ],
   msgFlags       => [ 
      qw( MSG_FLAGS_NOAUTHNOPRIV MSG_FLAGS_AUTH MSG_FLAGS_PRIV 
          MSG_FLAGS_REPORTABLE MSG_FLAGS_MASK )
   ],
   securityLevels => [
      qw( SECURITY_LEVEL_NOAUTHNOPRIV SECURITY_LEVEL_AUTHNOPRIV
          SECURITY_LEVEL_AUTHPRIV )
   ],
   securityModels => [
      qw( SECURITY_MODEL_ANY SECURITY_MODEL_SNMPV1 SECURITY_MODEL_SNMPV2C
          SECURITY_MODEL_USM )
   ],
   translate      => [
      qw( TRANSLATE_NONE TRANSLATE_OCTET_STRING TRANSLATE_NULL 
          TRANSLATE_TIMETICKS TRANSLATE_OPAQUE TRANSLATE_NOSUCHOBJECT 
          TRANSLATE_NOSUCHINSTANCE TRANSLATE_ENDOFMIBVIEW TRANSLATE_UNSIGNED 
          TRANSLATE_ALL )
   ],
   types          => [
      qw( INTEGER INTEGER32 OCTET_STRING NULL OBJECT_IDENTIFIER SEQUENCE
          IPADDRESS COUNTER COUNTER32 GAUGE GAUGE32 UNSIGNED32 TIMETICKS
          OPAQUE COUNTER64 NOSUCHOBJECT NOSUCHINSTANCE ENDOFMIBVIEW
          GET_REQUEST GET_NEXT_REQUEST GET_RESPONSE SET_REQUEST TRAP
          GET_BULK_REQUEST INFORM_REQUEST SNMPV2_TRAP REPORT HEX_STRING )
   ],
   utilities      => [ qw( asn1_ticks_to_time asn1_itoa ) ],
   versions       => [ qw( SNMP_VERSION_1 SNMP_VERSION_2C SNMP_VERSION_3 ) ]
);

Exporter::export_ok_tags( 
   qw( generictrap msgFlags securityLevels securityModels translate types 
       utilities versions ) 
);

$EXPORT_TAGS{ALL} = [ @EXPORT_OK ];

## ASN.1 Basic Encoding Rules type definitions

sub INTEGER()                  { 0x02 }  # INTEGER
sub INTEGER32()                { 0x02 }  # Integer32           - SNMPv2c
sub OCTET_STRING()             { 0x04 }  # OCTET STRING
sub HEX_STRING()               { 0xfe }  # OCTET STRING in HEX  # Work a Round
# [...]
# [public methods] -----------------------------------------------------------

sub new
{
   my ($class, %argv) = @_;

   # Create a new data structure for the object
   my $this = bless {
      '_buffer'      =>  '',              # Serialized message buffer
      '_error'       =>  undef,           # Error message
      '_index'       =>  0,               # Buffer index
      '_leading_dot' =>  FALSE,           # Prepend leading dot on OIDs
      '_length'      =>  0,               # Buffer length
      '_security'    =>  undef,           # Security Model object
      '_translate'   =>  TRANSLATE_NONE,  # Translation mode
      '_transport'   =>  undef,           # Transport Layer object
      '_version'     =>  SNMP_VERSION_1   # SNMP version
   }, $class;

   # Validate the passed arguments

   foreach (keys %argv) {

      if (/^-?callback$/i) {
         $this->callback($argv{$_});
      } elsif (/^-?debug$/i) {
         $this->debug($argv{$_});
      } elsif (/^-?leadingdot$/i) {
         $this->leading_dot($argv{$_});
      } elsif (/^-?msgid$/i) {
         $this->msg_id($argv{$_}); 
      } elsif (/^-?requestid$/i) {
         $this->request_id($argv{$_});
      } elsif (/^-?security$/i) {
         $this->security($argv{$_});
      } elsif (/^-?translate$/i) {
         $this->translate($argv{$_});
      } elsif (/^-?transport$/i) {
         $this->transport($argv{$_});
      } elsif (/^-?version$/i) {
         $this->version($argv{$_});
      } else {
         $this->_error("Invalid argument '%s'", $_);
      }

      if (defined($this->{_error})) {
         return wantarray ? (undef, $this->{_error}) : undef;
      }

   }

   return wantarray ? ($this, '') : $this;
}

{
   my $prepare_methods = {
      INTEGER,            \&_prepare_integer,
      OCTET_STRING,       \&_prepare_octet_string,
      NULL,               \&_prepare_null,
      OBJECT_IDENTIFIER,  \&_prepare_object_identifier,
      SEQUENCE,           \&_prepare_sequence,
      IPADDRESS,          \&_prepare_ipaddress,
      COUNTER,            \&_prepare_counter,
      GAUGE,              \&_prepare_gauge,
      TIMETICKS,          \&_prepare_timeticks,
      OPAQUE,             \&_prepare_opaque,
      COUNTER64,          \&_prepare_counter64,
      NOSUCHOBJECT,       \&_prepare_nosuchobject,
      NOSUCHINSTANCE,     \&_prepare_nosuchinstance,
      ENDOFMIBVIEW,       \&_prepare_endofmibview,
      GET_REQUEST,        \&_prepare_get_request,
      GET_NEXT_REQUEST,   \&_prepare_get_next_request,
      GET_RESPONSE,       \&_prepare_get_response,
      SET_REQUEST,        \&_prepare_set_request,
      TRAP,               \&_prepare_trap,
      GET_BULK_REQUEST,   \&_prepare_get_bulk_request,
      INFORM_REQUEST,     \&_prepare_inform_request,
      SNMPV2_TRAP,        \&_prepare_v2_trap,
      REPORT,             \&_prepare_report,
      HEX_STRING,         \&_prepare_hex_string
   };

   sub prepare 
   {
#     my ($this, $type, $value) = @_;

      return $_[0]->_error('ASN.1 type not defined') unless (@_ > 1);
      return $_[0]->_error if defined($_[0]->{_error});

      if (exists($prepare_methods->{$_[1]})) {
         $_[0]->${\$prepare_methods->{$_[1]}}($_[2]);
      } else {
         $_[0]->_error('Unknown ASN.1 type [%s]', $_[1]);
      }
   }
}

{
   my $process_methods = {
      INTEGER,            \&_process_integer32,
      OCTET_STRING,       \&_process_octet_string,
      NULL,               \&_process_null,
      OBJECT_IDENTIFIER,  \&_process_object_identifier,
      SEQUENCE,           \&_process_sequence,
      IPADDRESS,          \&_process_ipaddress,
      COUNTER,            \&_process_counter,
      GAUGE,              \&_process_gauge,
      TIMETICKS,          \&_process_timeticks,
      OPAQUE,             \&_process_opaque,
      COUNTER64,          \&_process_counter64,
      NOSUCHOBJECT,       \&_process_nosuchobject,
      NOSUCHINSTANCE,     \&_process_nosuchinstance,
      ENDOFMIBVIEW,       \&_process_endofmibview,
      GET_REQUEST,        \&_process_get_request,
      GET_NEXT_REQUEST,   \&_process_get_next_request,
      GET_RESPONSE,       \&_process_get_response,
      SET_REQUEST,        \&_process_set_request,
      TRAP,               \&_process_trap,
      GET_BULK_REQUEST,   \&_process_get_bulk_request,
      INFORM_REQUEST,     \&_process_inform_request,
      SNMPV2_TRAP,        \&_process_v2_trap,
      REPORT,             \&_process_report
   };

   sub process 
   {
#     my ($this, $expected, $found) = @_;

      return $_[0]->_error if defined($_[0]->{_error});
      return $_[0]->_error unless defined(my $type = $_[0]->_buffer_get(1));

      $type = unpack('C', $type);

      if (exists($process_methods->{$type})) {
         if ((@_ >= 2) && (defined($_[1])) && ($type != $_[1])) {
            return $_[0]->_error(
               'Expected %s, but found %s', asn1_itoa($_[1]), asn1_itoa($type)
            );
         }
         $_[2] = $type if (@_ == 3);
         $_[0]->${\$process_methods->{$type}}($type);
      } else {
         $_[0]->_error('Unknown ASN.1 type [0x%02x]', $type);
      }
   }
}

# [...]
# [private methods] ----------------------------------------------------------

#
# Basic Encoding Rules (BER) prepare methods
#

sub _prepare_type_length
{
#  my ($this, $type, $value) = @_;

   return $_[0]->_error('ASN.1 type not defined') unless defined($_[1]);

   my $length = CORE::length($_[2]);

   if ($length < 0x80) {
      $_[0]->_buffer_put(pack('C2', $_[1], $length) . $_[2]);
   } elsif ($length <= 0xff) {
      $_[0]->_buffer_put(pack('C3', $_[1], 0x81, $length) . $_[2]);
   } elsif ($length <= 0xffff) {
      $_[0]->_buffer_put(pack('CCn', $_[1], 0x82, $length) . $_[2]);
   } else {
      $_[0]->_error('Unable to prepare ASN.1 length');
   }
}

sub _prepare_integer
{
   my ($this, $value) = @_;

   return $this->_error('INTEGER value not defined') unless defined($value);

   if ($value !~ /^-?\d+$/) {
      return $this->_error('Expected numeric INTEGER value');
   }

   $this->_prepare_integer32(INTEGER, $value);
}

sub _prepare_unsigned32
{
   my ($this, $type, $value) = @_;

   if (!defined($value)) {
      return $this->_error('%s value not defined', asn1_itoa($type));
   }

   if ($value !~ /^\d+$/) {
      return $this->_error(
         'Expected positive numeric %s value', asn1_itoa($type)
      );
   }

   $this->_prepare_integer32($type, $value);
}

sub _prepare_integer32
{
   my ($this, $type, $value) = @_;

   # Determine if the value is positive or negative
   my $negative = ($value =~ /^-/);

   # Check to see if the most significant bit is set, if it is we
   # need to prefix the encoding with a zero byte.

   my $size   = 4;     # Assuming 4 byte integers
   my $prefix = FALSE;
   my $bytes  = '';

   if ((($value & 0xff000000) & 0x80000000) && (!$negative)) {
      $size++;
      $prefix = TRUE;
   }

   # Remove occurances of nine consecutive ones (if negative) or zeros
   # from the most significant end of the two's complement integer.

   while ((((!($value & 0xff800000))) ||
           ((($value & 0xff800000) == 0xff800000) && ($negative))) &&
           ($size > 1))
   {
      $size--;
      $value <<= 8;
   }

   # Add a zero byte so the integer is decoded as a positive value
   if ($prefix) {
      $bytes = pack('x');
      $size--;
   }

   # Build the integer
   while ($size-- > 0) {
      $bytes .= pack('C*', (($value & 0xff000000) >> 24));
      $value <<= 8;
   }

   # Encode ASN.1 header
   $this->_prepare_type_length($type, $bytes);
}

sub _prepare_octet_string
{
   my ($this, $value) = @_;

   if (!defined($value)) {
      return $this->_error('OCTET STRING value not defined');
   }

   $this->_prepare_type_length(OCTET_STRING, $value);
}

sub _prepare_hex_string
{
   my ($this, $value) = @_;

   if (!defined($value)) {
      return $this->_error('HEX STRING value not defined');
   }

   $this->_prepare_type_length(OCTET_STRING, pack("H*", $value));
}

sub _prepare_null
{
   $_[0]->_prepare_type_length(NULL, '');
}

# [...]

#
# Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1) utility functions
#

{
   my $types = {
      INTEGER,            'INTEGER',
      OCTET_STRING,       'OCTET STRING',
      NULL,               'NULL',
      OBJECT_IDENTIFIER,  'OBJECT IDENTIFIER',
      SEQUENCE,           'SEQUENCE',
      IPADDRESS,          'IpAddress',
      COUNTER,            'Counter',
      GAUGE,              'Gauge',
      TIMETICKS,          'TimeTicks',
      OPAQUE,             'Opaque',
      COUNTER64,          'Counter64',
      NOSUCHOBJECT,       'noSuchObject',
      NOSUCHINSTANCE,     'noSuchInstance',
      ENDOFMIBVIEW,       'endOfMibView',
      GET_REQUEST,        'GetRequest-PDU',
      GET_NEXT_REQUEST,   'GetNextRequest-PDU',
      GET_RESPONSE,       'GetResponse-PDU',
      SET_REQUEST,        'SetRequest-PDU',
      TRAP,               'Trap-PDU',
      GET_BULK_REQUEST,   'GetBulkRequest-PDU',
      INFORM_REQUEST,     'InformRequest-PDU',
      SNMPV2_TRAP,        'SNMPv2-Trap-PDU',
      REPORT,             'Report-PDU',
      HEX_STRING,         'HEX STRING'
   };

   sub asn1_itoa
   {
      my ($type) = @_;

      return '??' unless (@_ == 1);

      if (exists($types->{$type})) {
         $types->{$type};
      } else {
         sprintf('?? [0x%02x]', $type);
      }
   }
}

sub asn1_ticks_to_time
{
   my $ticks = shift || 0;

   my $days = int($ticks / (24 * 60 * 60 * 100));
   $ticks %= (24 * 60 * 60 * 100);

   my $hours = int($ticks / (60 * 60 * 100));
   $ticks %= (60 * 60 * 100);

   my $minutes = int($ticks / (60 * 100));
   $ticks %= (60 * 100);

   my $seconds = ($ticks / 100);

   if ($days != 0){
      sprintf('%d day%s, %02d:%02d:%05.02f', $days,
         ($days == 1 ? '' : 's'), $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
   } elsif ($hours != 0) {
      sprintf('%d hour%s, %02d:%05.02f', $hours,
         ($hours == 1 ? '' : 's'), $minutes, $seconds);
   } elsif ($minutes != 0) {
      sprintf('%d minute%s, %05.02f', $minutes,
         ($minutes == 1 ? '' : 's'), $seconds);
   } else {
      sprintf('%04.02f second%s', $seconds, ($seconds == 1 ? '' : 's'));
   }
}

#
# Error handlers
#

#[...]
# ============================================================================
1; # [end Net::SNMP::Message]
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a character \x03 in your file.  That is "end of text" in ASCII.  It might be either your `.pl` file itself or something that is loaded by it.

If you see something like `^C` or `^B` at the start of your file, delete it.  You might have to use a hex editor otherwise.

One thing that strikes me, though, is the mentioning of "PK".  Could it be that you are trying to execute a pk-zipped file?

Comment: Hi Svante if u have a look at my code u can easily find out that there is no /x03 in my file & its not pk-zipped file ,my file name is snmpget.pl.

Comment: What I _do_ see is that there seems to be a `/` missing at the indicated place (line 1, column 3).  Could it be that it has been replaced by `\x03`, which is unprintable?  You should perhaps really verify this with a hex editor.